# Sulu: adding tags field to custom entity

Tags: taxonomy, sulu

How to add tags field to custom entity? What kind of (doctrine) field type it should be? I can't find any documentation nor example about that.

**Update:**

I followed @Prokyon's instructions and added field to my custom entity and not it looks like this:

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\VenueRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation as Serializer;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Sulu\Bundle\MediaBundle\Entity\MediaInterface;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\Accessor;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;
use Sulu\Bundle\TagBundle\Tag\TagInterface;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\Type;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=VenueRepository::class)
 */
class Venue
{

    const RESOURCE_KEY = 'venue';
    const SECURITY_CONTEXT = 'sulu.matchcentre.venues';

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private ?string $locationName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private ?string $shortName;

    /**
     * @var MediaInterface|null
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Sulu\Bundle\MediaBundle\Entity\MediaInterface")
     *
     * @Serializer\Exclude
     */
    private $image = null;


    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private ?string $googleMapsLink;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="smallint")
     */
    private ?int $country;


    /**
     * @var Collection<int, TagInterface>
     * @Accessor(getter="getTagNameArray")
     * @Groups({"fullContact"})
     * @Type("array")
     */
    protected $tags;

    /**
     * @var Collection<string, VenueTranslation>
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\VenueTranslation", mappedBy="venue", cascade={"ALL"}, indexBy="locale")
     *
     * @Serializer\Exclude
     */
    private $translations;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $locale;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->translations = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->tags = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getLocationName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->locationName;
    }

    public function setLocationName(?string $locationName): self
    {
        $this->locationName = $locationName;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getShortName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->shortName;
    }

    public function setShortName(?string $shortName): self
    {
        $this->shortName = $shortName;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @Serializer\VirtualProperty(name="description")
     */
    public function getDescription(): ?string
    {
        $translation = $this->getTranslation($this->locale);
        if (!$translation) {
            return null;
        }
        return $translation->getDescription();
    }

    public function setDescription(?string $description): self
    {
        $translation = $this->getTranslation($this->locale);
        if (!$translation) {
            $translation = $this->createTranslation($this->locale);
        }
        $translation->setDescription($description);
        return $this;
    }

    public function getImage(): ?MediaInterface
    {
        return $this->image;
    }

    /**
     * @return array<string, mixed>|null
     *
     * @Serializer\VirtualProperty
     * @Serializer\SerializedName("image")
     */
    public function getImageData(): ?array
    {
        if (!$this->image) {
            return null;
        }

        return [
            'id' => $this->image->getId(),
        ];
    }

    public function setImage(?MediaInterface $image): self
    {
        $this->image = $image;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getGoogleMapsLink(): ?string
    {
        return $this->googleMapsLink;
    }

    public function setGoogleMapsLink(?string $googleMapsLink): self
    {
        $this->googleMapsLink = $googleMapsLink;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getCountry(): ?int
    {
        return $this->country;
    }

    public function setCountry(?int $country): self
    {
        $this->country = $country;
        return $this;
    }

    public function addTag(TagInterface $tag)
    {
        $this->tags[] = $tag;

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeTag(TagInterface $tag)
    {
        $this->tags->removeElement($tag);
    }

    public function getTags()
    {
        return $this->tags;
    }

    public function getTagNameArray()
    {
        $tags = [];

        foreach ($this->getTags() as $tag) {
            $tags[] = $tag->getName();
        }

        return $tags;
    }

    public function getLocale(): string
    {
        return $this->locale;
    }

    public function setLocale(string $locale): self
    {
        $this->locale = $locale;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return VenueTranslation[]
     */
    public function getTranslations(): array
    {
        return $this->translations->toArray();
    }

    protected function getTranslation(string $locale): ?VenueTranslation
    {
        if (!$this->translations->containsKey($locale)) {
            return null;
        }

        return $this->translations->get($locale);
    }

    protected function createTranslation(string $locale): VenueTranslation
    {
        $translation = new VenueTranslation($this, $locale);
        $this->translations->set($locale, $translation);

        return $translation;
    }
}
```

But problem is that when I try to run:

```
bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff
```

I get response: "*No changes detected in your mapping information.*"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way is to take a look at existing sulu entities with tags e.g. `Account` or `Contact`.

The property can be implemented like this:

```
 /**
 * @var Collection<int, TagInterface>
 */
protected $tags;
```

See [Conctact.php](https://github.com/sulu/sulu/blob/2.x/src/Sulu/Bundle/ContactBundle/Entity/Contact.php#L144) for more details.

and the doctrine mapping can be configured like this:

```
     <many-to-many field="tags" target-entity="Sulu\Bundle\TagBundle\Tag\TagInterface">
        <join-table name="co_contact_tags">
            <join-columns>
                <join-column name="idContacts" referenced-column-name="id"/>
            </join-columns>
            <inverse-join-columns>
                <join-column name="idTags" referenced-column-name="id"/>
            </inverse-join-columns>
        </join-table>
    </many-to-many>
```

See [Contact.orm.xml](https://github.com/sulu/sulu/blob/2.x/src/Sulu/Bundle/ContactBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/Contact.orm.xml#L180-L192) for the complete doctrine configuraton of the entity.

Furthermore you can read here more about the doctrine entity configurations [doctrine mapping](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.8/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-unidirectional)

**Update:**

the annotations you added to the `$tag` property are only for the serialization. You don't really need them. But your are completely missing the doctrine annotations for the mapping.

Here is an example for the correct doctrine annotations, but you still have to adjust the tables and mapped-columns for your entities. Check the link above about the doctrine mapping for more clarification.

```
    /**
 * Many Users have Many Groups.
 * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Sulu\Bundle\TagBundle\Tag\TagInterface")
 * @JoinTable(name="venue_tags",
 *      joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="venue_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="idTags", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *      )
 */
private $tags;
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried adding $tags field from your first snipped (with annotations, of course) but when I run bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff it says "No changes detected in your mapping information." ?! I have all the imports from top. Any idea?

Comment: @MilanG It is kinda hard to help you this way, maybe you can edit your question with a code snippet of the annotation
I additionally added a link for the doctrine documentation regarding this topic